# The cards width is not adjusting to same width size along with only 3 cards in a row

Tags: css, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

Hello I am trying to adjust the cards in th UI using angular-flex. The width of the cards are responsive as per the text length in it. But I want each card to be of same width irrespective of the content within it.

If I am using `max-width`, then that is effecting the cards in mobile responsive. Else in responsive view all the card is same size and width.

If I am using `display:grid;` then the cards are perfect. But I need to do this responsive using flex so I had used `display:flex;`

*This is the UI:-*

[image: UI]

*The HTML :-*

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="cont">
    <app-overview *ngFor="let item of data" [extra]="item.extra" [colorcode]="item.color" [ovrno]="item.value" [ovrtitle]="item.info" >
    </app-overview>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS:-*

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .cont {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: stretch;  

}
}
```

1. How can I show same card-width irrespective of the content length ?

   **PS:-** Also, I want to avoid using media query. How can I do the same for different views using flex only ?
2. Also need to show only 3 cards in a row.

**EDIT:-**

*app-overview component :-*

*HTML:-*

```
<div class="overview" [ngStyle]="getColor()" (click)="onSelect()">
    <p class="no">{{no}}</p>
    <p class="otitle">{{title}}</p>
</div>
```

*CSS:-*

```
.overview {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 270px;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  .no {
    font-size: 6.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
  }
  .otitle {
    font-size: 25px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about no media queries... that's a strange requirement since they're 97.97% supported according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mediaqueries). But you can do all this with a single media query rule or skip it and have 3 really squished boxes per row.

On your parent element you only need two rules:

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And on the children you'll need a little bit of math: The margin (how much distance you need between your cards) plus the horizontal padding inside the cards multiplied by 2 is the final flex value in your larger screen media query, for example:

```
.child {
    margin: .5rem; /* This value plus the left to right padding * 2 == final flex value */
    padding: 2rem .25rem; /* Padding given for example on inner element */  
    flex: 100%;
    display: flex;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) { /* Or whatever breakpoint makes your content not look janky */
    .child {
        flex: 0 1 calc(33.33333% - 1.5rem); /* (.5 + .25)*2 = 1.5rem this is the final flex value */
    }
}
```

Why this works well: On smaller screens (the default) setting `flex: 100%` is the equivalent of setting flex-basis to 100% (since we're providing a unit) which fills the width when we want to stack elements.

On larger screens the flex-basis (last number in flex property) is being explicitly set as 1/3 of the screen width minus the sum of the horizontal margin and padding of the element inside the container which forces each one to take up 1/3 of the screen, while the flex-grow (first number in the flex property) is being set to 0 otherwise the rows with less than three will grow to share the space available.

Here's a [working example](https://svelte.dev/repl/40276031693c44d1b7e9690139ffa123?version=3.19.1) I made with Svelte based on your image but the concept of the CSS is identical so it shouldn't matter what framework you're using.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the wonderful explanation. I tried with your solution. but the title is going out from the card in my case. I am not getting why it happened since in yours it is working fine. In you `Overview.svelte` file `<div>` section I guess in my case it is `app-overview` is the child. I included in the css as yours but it is not getting proper.

Comment: You can inspect the HTML output in the browser and find the real child of the container. With CSS if the direct children of your .cont are custom elements you should be able to target them directly  `app-overview {...styles}` is perfectly valid as far as I know.

Comment: Included EDIT on my question. On `app-overview` component I have these style as before. When I am replacing this with your's example it is not working.

Comment: Can you post an edit to your question with the actual output from the browser? Just inspect the code and show what renders. CSS doesn't quite care about what happens in your framework code, it cares about the actual HTML structure of the output. My guess is that there is extra markup being injected that you're not aware of.

Comment: It is fine now. Little it padding was needed . Thanks again